# Using a string key to return a value from an array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

I have a named array of 14 rows by 2 columns. The first has a string key (ie: `Country`), and the second an attribute (ie: `Owner`).  I want to retrieve the `Owner` by supplying the `Country`.

I only know how to use =INDEX to retrieve values from named arrays, but that expects col/row numbers.

How might I achieve my requirement?

Comment: Consider using **VLOOKUP()** .

Comment: 5 seconds after I posted it, a spark appeared and it suggested vlookup LOL...  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of an answer.

Feed the INDEX function with a MATCH function to provide the requisite row number, along the lines:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,A:A,0))
```

VLOOKUP will work but INDEX/MATCH is more powerful ([see](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2011/03/the-imposing-index.html)) so if you are already comfortable with INDEX it might be better to add MATCH to your arsenal rather than to bother with V/H LOOKUP.